# How does docker interpret CMD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, unicorn

## Initial Attemtp

I have a Dockerfile in my rails project, that ends with:

```
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "unicorn", "-D", "-c /usr/src/app/config/unicorn.rb"]
```

When I run a container I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -  /usr/src/app/config/unicorn.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:75:in `reload'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:68:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:100:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

Which I don't understand, because when I change the CMD to `CMD ["cat", "config/unicorn.rb"]`, `docker run <image>` **correctly outputs the file**.

## CMD as a shell

After some try and error I found out that:

```
CMD bundle exec unicorn -D -c /usr/src/app/config/unicorn.rb
```

**works fine**.

## Correct attempt

After consulting the [Docker docs](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd) I saw that when using the format `CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]` it is **required to give the full path** to the executable. This I did not do in my initial attempt.

I went on an changed the CMD to:

```
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/bundle", "exec", "unicorn", "-D", "-c /usr/src/app/config/unicorn.rb"]
```

which **worked**!

## Question

What's confusing me, is that in the initial attempt `bundle exec unicorn` still ran, but just did not find the config file.

Can anybody exaplain this behaviour? Why did my intial attemp run, **but not find the file** and the other two versions work fine?

## Edit

For anybody looking to reproduce this. Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM benjaminbauer/ruby:latest

ONBUILD EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/bundle", "exec", "unicorn", "-D", "-c /usr/src/app/config/unicorn.rb"]
```

The `benjaminbauer/ruby` is just a fork of the [official ruby image](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby) with [cached bundle install](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/pull/1). Use the `cache_bundle_install` [branch](https://github.com/benjaminbauer/ruby/tree/cache_bundle_install) if you want to build it.

Comment: My first guess would be that you have different version of ruby? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Have you tried splitting `"-c /usr/src/app/config/unicorn.rb"` into two separate arguments inside the `CMD [...]` array?

Comment: @MishaBrukman Yes, I did. Fails too

Comment: Have you tried without -D option?

Comment: @Michel what do you expect will change?

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue, and the full path did not solve it. I just switched to the "command line" version from the docker doc, ie: `/usr/local/bundle/bin/unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb` and it worked. I have absolutely NO idea why...